# Non exhaustive pattern while using as-pattern

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement my own groupBy function (similar to the Prelude's one) using foldr.

The following definition seems to work:

```
myGroupBy p xs = foldr step [] xs
                  where step x acc
                          | null acc = [[x]]
                          | p x (head (head acc)) = (x:head acc):(tail acc)
                          | otherwise = [x]:acc
```

Since I was using `head acc/tail acc` in this multiple times, though I can improve it by using an as-pattern. So I changed this to:

```
myGroupByNew p xs = foldr step [] xs
                  where step x acc@(a:b)
                          | null acc = [[x]]
                          | null b = [[x]]
                          | p x (head a) = (x:a):b
                          | otherwise = [x]:acc
```

However, this method now gives me a non-exhaustive pattern error. I cannot understand, I have checked for `null acc` and `null b`, so assuming `a` cannot be null. As for x, have not put any guard clause for it in the previous method too.

I am a bit lost what is the pattern that I am missing.

Comment: I think that if `acc` is `[]`, it won't match the pattern `(a:b)`, so maybe the pattern missing is `step x []`.

Comment: `acc == []` is covered by `null acc`

Comment: @peeyushsingh But that check is only performed after the `acc@(a:b)` pattern is matched, so it doesn't help.

Comment: a bit too trigger happy these days....not sure why the question was down voted...

Comment: A small suggestion: turning warnings on should report, at compile time, that `step` does not handle the empty list `[]`. Recommended.

Comment: @chi thanks, will try it later at the other machine, right now am compiling using the repl online editor so not sure if the option is available there.

Comment: You can add at the very top of your `.hs` file the line `{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}` to enable warnings. Otherwise, in GHCi you can use the command `:set -Wall`, but you have to do that every time you open ghci.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`acc@(a:b)` will only ever match a non empty list. The `@` just gives an alias for the value, but the pattern still needs to match.

its as if you have a function like this (albeit in a smarter way):

```
step x (a:b) = 
  let acc = (a:b) in
  ....
```

You can clearly see here that `step` doesn't ever match if you call `step x []`

Responding to the comment:

```
step x null = [[x]]
```

Gives a redundant match because `null` is a function that checks for the empty list. It is not a data constructor so using the name in the pattern match just is a "wildcard" (it always matches).
You want to match the empty data constructor `[]`.

try:

```
step x [] = [[x]]
step x acc@(a:b)
  | null b = [[x]]
  | p x (head a) = (x:a):b
  | otherwise = [x]:acc
```

Comment: Understood, but if I check for `null acc` seperately  by including `step x null = [[x]]` before the rest of definition `step x acc@(a:b)....` then I get an overmatch exception. Can you show me how to re-write it?

Comment: Thanks, that worked, had tried `step x null` (which is obviously wrong) earlier...